# Spring Boot Application Error Page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm starting to learn Spring Boot, and I'm following a tutorial on youtube. However, there is an weird thing happening on my project. I just created a Controller called **GreetingController**. Below is the complete code of the class

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class GreetingController {

    private static BigInteger nextId;

    private static Map<BigInteger, Greeting> greetingMap;

    private static Greeting save(Greeting greeting) {
        if (greetingMap == null) {
            greetingMap = new HashMap<BigInteger, Greeting>();
            nextId = BigInteger.ONE;
        }
        greeting.setId(nextId);
        nextId = nextId.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        greetingMap.put(greeting.getId(), greeting);
        return greeting;
    }

    static {
        Greeting g1 = new Greeting();
        g1.setText("Hello World");
        save(g1);

        Greeting g2 = new Greeting();
        g2.setText("Hola Mundo");
        save(g2);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/greetings", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>> getGreetings() {

        Collection<Greeting> greetings = greetingMap.values();

        return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>>(greetings,
                HttpStatus.OK);

    }

}
```

The controller is under the following package:

[image]

However, when I bootstrap the application with the URL `http://localhost:8080/api/greetings` the following error appears on my page:

[image]

But, when I put the GreetingController in the same package of **Application** class, as the image below:

[image]

And then get the same URL `http://localhost:8080/api/greetings`, I got the right response:

[image]

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Did you setup your view resolver to find the correct path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your `com.example` package to `org.example`. Spring boot scans for controllers all subpackages of package of class when you place your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Or put `@ComponentScan("org.example")` on the same class. This way you tell spring boot where to search your controllers (and other beans).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support having a controller in another package, you need to include it in the component scan of your Application.

In `Application.java`, you could add the following:

`@ComponentScan({com.example, org.example})`

By default, the package that Application is in will be included in the ComponentScan, which is why it was working for you when you had the controller in the same package as Application.

Also, you don't need the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation on your controller, FYI.